# requirejs -- how to add request headers to calls that load script files

Tags: requirejs, content-security-policy

I am using requirejs in my GUI app.  So all my script files are managed by the require library.  Now I am required to add a request header like "script-src"  with a suitable value, in order to meet the Content-Security-Policy as defined here: http://content-security-policy.com/

My question is, does RequireJS provide any callback hooks for adding xhr headers to the script loader function.  Or is there is any other alternate way